# Assert on intermediate state for async functions without the 'act' error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, jestjs

I have a `loading` state, and a function that cycles it, fetching and setting the data in between:

```js
async function getData(fetch) {
  setLoading(true);
  setData(await fetch());
  setLoading(false);
}
```

Using `await act()` waits for the state to stabilize, meaning that any assertion on `loading === true` fails.

```js
it('cycles loading',async () => {
   // ... renderHook
   await act(getData)
   await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.loading).toBe(true)) // This always fails
   await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.data).toBe(newData)) // This passes
   await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.loading).toBe(false))// This passes
}
```

The one way I get it to work is to not use `act()`

```js
it('cycles loading',await () => {
   // ... renderHook
   getData(); // Gives act warning
   await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.loading).toBe(true)) // This passes
   await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.data).toBe(newData)) // This passes
   await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.loading).toBe(false))// This passes
}
```

I've tried to use promises while enclosing the call in an act and asserting in the act:

```
it('cycles loading',async () => {
   // ... renderHook
   let resolve;
   const fetch = () => new Promise(res => {resolve = res})
   await act(() => {
     getData();
     waitFor(() => expect(result.current.loading).toBe(true)) // This passes
     resolve(newData);
   }  
   await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.data).toBe(newData)) // This passes
   await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.loading).toBe(false))// This passes
   // Still getting act error...
}
```

These tests are 100% semantically correct but they represent the iterations I've tried to get this type of test to work. Any help is appreciated.

**Pre posting edit**

After trying one more iteration, I got it to work, but I'm not sure why. This is the version that works and any insight as to why would be greatly appreciated.

What I did was move the promise resolution out of the `act()`

```js
it('cycles loading',async () => {
   // ... renderHook
   let resolve;
   const fetch = () => new Promise(res => {resolve = res})
   await act(() => {
     getData();
     waitFor(() => expect(result.current.loading).toBe(true)) // This passes
   }
   resolve(newData);
   await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.data).toBe(newData)) // This passes
   await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.loading).toBe(false))// This passes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of `getData` is flawed with async vs sync processing logic.

It should be done like this:

```
async function getData(fetch) {    
    setLoading(true);
    return fetch().finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
    });
}
```

Then all your tests become simple, you just wait for one promise, that's all. And the rejection won't affect the status.